# Stop prompting to Block Number when deleting a text message

Tags: sms, samsung-galaxy-s-9

I have a Samsung Galaxy S9+ and every time I delete any text message, the phone prompts the option to "Block Number". How do I disable this so I can just select the message(s) I want to delete?  My work requires a lot of two factor authentication, so I get a lot of texts with temporary pins to enter in our software. I delete the texts each time as I don't want my messages view being congested, but this prompt drives me nuts as it is since I already have to do 2FA for everything at work.